# How to calculate the Fourier series for spike train given the Fourier series of square wave?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, signal-processing

I can calculate the Fourier series for square wave using the Fourier series of spike train using the properties of Fourier series. Noting that square wave is actually the integration of a one positive and one negative spike trains with equal frequency. I was wondering if the opposite is also possible.

Comment: Take the derivative. Now you have the signal minus its shifted (i.e. $x(t)-x(t-T/2)$).